# The suitability of a procedural programming language for graphical applications

Tags: oop, window, console-application, procedural-programming, graphical-programming

Is anyone able to explain or evaluate the suitability of a procedural programming language for graphical applications, against object orientated programming for instance. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

Comment: google is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use either since you will probably be using some framework to design the GUI.

For example, if you are considering C then you will probably use GTK as framework. But you can still use the C bindings for other frameworks such as WxWidgets (written in C++).

*But:* Procedural Programming isn't really strong because **a GUI isn't a procedure.**

A procedural environment relies on location in the program (which
usually translates to time) to distinguish between different kinds of
interactions.  A GUI environment relies on location on the screen to
distinguish between different kinds of interactions.

So, in a procedural environment you either smush everything together,
so you have a place in the program which does everything, or you have
a fake GUI, only some parts of the screen will work at any specific
point in time.

That said, I should point out that it's not impossible to write a
decent GUI from a procedural environment -- it's just a bit tricky.

And then there's the other way of looking at it:  *a GUI is like,
chocolate, with lots of caramel*, and **a procedure is, like, all this
paperwork**. They just don't mix all that well.